# Seed rails db with I18n data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, yaml, rails-i18n, seed

On rails 5.2, I want to populate my db with :en and :pt languages, I try :

```
Product.create!(
  process:  t('washed'),
  category: coffee)
```

and then I give the translations in my en.yml and pt.yml files. I got this error message:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `t' for main:Object
```

Any ideas?

---EDITED----

I thought Ifound out the solution, but I can't make it work with nested attributes:

in my seed.rb:

```
Product.create!(
 name:'Cerro de Jesus farm',
 process: I18n.t('process'),
 cupping_notes: I18n.t('cup_notes.nica_cp'),
  category: coffee)
```

in my pt.yml :

```
pt:
 process: "lavado"
 cup_notes:
  nica_cp: 'café, limão'
  columb_cp: 'limão'
```

and in my view :

```
<p><%= t('cup_notes', cupping_notes:@product.cupping_notes)%></p>
```

the view displays the whole hash :  Cupping notes: {:nica_cp=>“café, limão”, :columb_cp=>“limão”}

Any idea about what I missed? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`t` is shorthand for `I18n.t`, but only works in views and helpers. In a controller or model use `I18n.t`

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#the-public-i18n-api

If you wish to make this part of your view you need to do the following:

pt.yml

```
pt:
 process: "lavado"
 cup_notes:
  nica_cp: 'café, limão'
  columb_cp: 'limão'
```

In your view:

```
<p><%= t("cup_notes.#{@product.cupping_notes}")%></p>
```

**For reference**

Your attempt to use:

```
<p><%= t('cup_notes', cupping_notes:@product.cupping_notes)%></p>
```

didn't work because the second argument is used to pass variables to a specific translation.

For example, if I had this in my translations:

```
pt:
  number_of_lemons: "%{number} limões"
``

Then I can do this in my view:
```

```

See [Translation Variables](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#passing-variables-to-translations) for more info.

Comment: I still can't make my view display the Portuguese translation. 
<%=@product.process  %> on my view displays "washed" and not "lavado", even if the url is the right one. I am stuck here..

Comment: Thanks again Tom, this is definitely what I was missing.  I edited the question, and accepted your answer ;)

Comment: Just a detail for those who face the same problem: the attribute in the seed should then be set  now like this  :
 cupping_notes: I18n.t('nica_cp')

Comment: Thanks @cecileRx, glad to help.